# to merge images with condition less than height 2450 pixel by using python, tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, merge, python-imaging-library, tkinter-entry

I made a program to merge images and I want to upgrade this program that the total height of the images should be less than 2450 pixel and save each merged images.

```
import os
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import  tkinter.messagebox as msgbox
from tkinter import *    # __all__
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import  Image

# add file
def add_file():
files = filedialog.askopenfilenames(title="이미지 파일을 선택하세요", \
    filetypes =(('jpg 파일', '*.jpg'), ('모든 파일', '*.*')), \
    initialdir='D:/jh/사업/프로그램/파이썬 이미지 합치기 프로그램/image')
    
# file list that user can select
for file in files:
    list_file.insert(END, file)



# file frame(file add, selected file delete)
file_frame = Frame(root)
file_frame.pack(fill='x', padx=5, pady=5)

btn_add_file = Button(file_frame, padx=5, pady=5, width=12, text='파일추가', command=add_file)
btn_add_file.pack(side='left')

btn_del_file = Button(file_frame, padx=5, pady=5, width=12, text='선택삭제', command=del_file)
btn_del_file.pack(side='right')

# list frame
list_frame = Frame(root)
list_frame.pack(fill='both', padx=5, pady=5)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(list_frame)
scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')

list_file = Listbox(list_frame, selectmode='extended', height=12, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
list_file.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)
scrollbar.config(command=list_file.yview)

.....

 dest_path = os.path.join(txt_dest_path.get(), txt_file.get())   
 # txt_file get values after to input entry for file name. ex) desk 
 result_img.save(dest_path)   #save result_img to dest_path
 msgbox.showinfo('알림', '작업이 완료되었습니다.')
```

in this coding, list_file is Listbox and there are several images which are the same widths but are different heights. I want to merge this image but the height of the merged image should not over 2450 pixel.

for example, list_file is a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6. And height of images in list_file is 200, 1500, 2400, 100, 300, 500, 1600. Then list_file should a0 <-(a0+a1), a1<-(a2), a2<-(a3, a4, a5), a3<-(a6)
[1700, 2400, 900, 1600]

And I want to get entry value and save each images of list_file. For example entry value is desk, the file name should be desk 001.jpg, desk 002.jpg, desk 003.jpg, desk 004.jpg, etc.

Comment: You've told us what you want, but haven't explained what you need help with. What problem are you having that is preventing you from doing this?

Comment: Actually, I want to change list_file by merging images and save the list_file. However, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: How do you insert images to the `Listbox`?Or are there only the file name of pictures in `Listbox`?

Comment: I added the coding about how to insert images to the Listbox. It has path + file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Image.new(...)` to create the merged image and then use `Image.paste(...)` to copy the required images into the merged image:

```
def merge_images(imagelist, width, height, seqno):
    if imagelist:
        # create the merged image
        merged_image = Image.new('RGB', (width, height), (0,0,0))
        y = 0
        for image in imagelist:
            merged_image.paste(image, (0, y))
            y += image.height
        # save the merged image
        dest_path = os.path.join(txt_dest_path.get(), 'desk%03d.jpg' % seqno)
        merged_image.save(dest_path)
        seqno += 1
    return seqno

def merge():
    MAX_HEIGHT = 2450
    merge_list = []
    height = 0
    width = None
    seqno = 1
    for file in list_file.get(0, 'end'):
        image = Image.open(file)
        if width is None:
            width = image.width
        if height+image.height <= MAX_HEIGHT:
            merge_list.append(image)
            height += image.height
        else:
            seqno = merge_images(merge_list, width, height, seqno)
            merge_list = [image]
            height = image.height

    merge_images(merge_list, width, height, seqno)
```